# LaTeX - using HA-prosper - Error : \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}

Tags: hyperref, errors

I have started using the `HA-Prosper` packages with a very simple code, but I get an error, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{prosper}
\usepackage{HA-prosper}
\title{Internet Traffic}
\author{A.B}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

While this a fairly simple code to just create  the title, I am getting this sticky error:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `ps2pdf',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4198 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is produced because you are running your code using `pdflatex` and you can't use `pdflatex` directly with the `prosper` document class; you can use `latex` to run your document and produce a `.dvi` file and then turn this into `.ps` format to finally convert it into `.pdf` format. Your editor most probably has ways to automate this process.

However, since `prosper` and `HA-prosper` are outdated, I would suggest you to use another document class for your presentations: [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) or [`powerdot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/powerdot).

Comment: thanks alot for your help however I am using Miktek v 2.9 ! its not compatible with prosper either ?

Comment: @shahb it's not really a problem of compatibility with your LaTeX distribution (MiKTeX); the problem is that with `prosper` you cannot compile directly with `pdflatex` but you have to follow the route I indicated in my answer (`latex->dvi->ps->pdf`). The most important thing is that `prosper` is outdated; currently there are better document classes; `beamer` or `powerdot`.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina thanks a lot .. I really appreciate it ..and gonna start using Beamer..
by the way I am curious how to produce the dvi file ?

Comment: @shahb as I said in my answer, use `latex` to compile your document. Which editor do you use? (TeXworks, TeXnicCenter...?)